# WordPress : Stretched Background Image in IE8

Tags: css, wordpress, internet-explorer-8, background-image

I badly need your help. My background image was overly stretched in IE8.

I used Wordpress's functionality on background image in their edit appearance. Chrome, Firefox and other IE versions, the background is appearing okay. But when I checked in IE8, it was overly stretched. Instead of seeing the garden background, what I saw was the tip of a tree which was part of the garden.

I was wondering on where I can tweak the code or what I can do to make it fit nicely like how other browsers show it.

I already tried :

- `background-size:cover`
- `background-size:1024px 100%;`

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the HTML and css in question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill

download **backgroundsize.min.htc**

```
.selector { 
    background-size: cover;    
    -ms-behavior: url(css/backgroundsize.min.htc);
     behavior: url(css/backgroundsize.min.htc);
}
```